# Why is route not found when using Origin header

Tags: c#, http, curl, cors, asp.net-web-api2

My WebAPI 2.1 service returns a 404 "route not found" error when requesting OPTIONS /project/{id}.  I am using attribute based routing.

Using CuRL, I've discovered that the request succeeds when I leave out the Origin header.

I have enabled CORS, setup my controller like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("project")]
public class ProjectController : ApiController
{
    protected ProjectRepo Repo;

    public ProjectController()
    {
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == HttpMethod.Options.ToString())
            return;

        Repo = new ProjectRepo();
    }

    [Route("{id?}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Options(int? id = null)
    {
        return new HttpResponseMessage { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK };
    }

}
```

The web.config is set to allow all origins:

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Accept, Authorization, Origin, Content-Type, X-Requested-With" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers" value="Accept, Origin, Content-Type, X-Requested-With" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

The first CuRL request fails with a 404, yet the next request succeed once I remove the Origin header.

**1.  CuRL request passing Origin header returns 400 Not Found:**

```
$ curl -v -H "Origin: http://localhost:51696/project/1" \
-H "Access-Control-Request-Method: DELETE" -X OPTIONS \
http://localhost:51696/project/1

* Adding handle: conn: 0x4c3378
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x4c3378) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to localhost port 51696 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 51696 (#0)
> OPTIONS /project/1 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: localhost:51696
> Accept: */*
> Origin: http://localhost:51696/project/1
> Access-Control-Request-Method: DELETE
>
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Expires: -1
* Server Microsoft-IIS/8.0 is not blacklisted
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?YzpccHJvamVjdHNcYW5hbHl0aWNzXENvbVNlcnZpY2VcQ29tU2VydmljZVxwcm9qZWN0XDE=?=
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Authorization, Origin, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-360i-Authorization
< Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Accept, Origin, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-360i-Authorization
< Date: Mon, 19 May 2014 16:29:45 GMT
< Content-Length: 197
<
{"Message":"No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:51696/project/1'.","MessageDetail":"No action was found on the controller
'Project' that matches the request."}* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

**2.  CuRL request without Origin header returns 200 OK:**

```
$ curl -v -H "Access-Control-Request-Method: DELETE" -X OPTIONS \
http://localhost:51696/project/1

* Adding handle: conn: 0x1d63238
* Adding handle: send: 0
* Adding handle: recv: 0
* Curl_addHandleToPipeline: length: 1
* - Conn 0 (0x1d63238) send_pipe: 1, recv_pipe: 0
* About to connect() to localhost port 51696 (#0)
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 51696 (#0)
> OPTIONS /project/1 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.30.0
> Host: localhost:51696
> Accept: */*
> Access-Control-Request-Method: DELETE
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: -1
* Server Microsoft-IIS/8.0 is not blacklisted
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?YzpccHJvamVjdHNcYW5hbHl0aWNzXENvbVNlcnZpY2VcQ29tU2VydmljZVxwcm9qZWN0XDE=?=
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, OPTIONS, PUT, POST, DELETE, HEAD
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Authorization, Origin, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-360i-Authorization
< Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Accept, Origin, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-360i-Authorization
< Date: Mon, 19 May 2014 16:29:03 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
<
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty new to all this so you might have already thought of the following but, since it wasn't clear in your question, I thought I'd mention it.

How did you enable CORS? You can do that per-controller, per-action or globally. Looking at the controller code in your question, I can't see any `[EnableCors(...)]` attributes to your controller or any actions, so perhaps you did that globally? If so, did you use a `EnableCorsAttribute` instance:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("www.example.com", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

or did you just do:

```
config.EnableCors();
```

which isn't enough by itself?

Comment: Originally, I enabled cors by calling EnableCors().  I was able to fix the problem by passing in an EnableCorsAttribute instance:
 EnableCorsAttribute("*","*","*")
AND removing the Access-Control-* headers from web.config

Answer (score 0):

It works after I enable CORS like so:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

and commented most of the Access-Control-* headers in web.config:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <!--  enable CorsAttribute explicitly in WebApiConfig.cs
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Accept, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, X-Requested-With, X-360i-Authorization" />
        -->
        <add name="Access-Control-Expose-Headers" value="Accept, Origin, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, X-360i-Authorization" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
```